# How to read a dynamically changing file

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to read a constantly changing log file (that is text file) and generate an alert on some text found in that file. I want to do it through bash scripting but I'm confused that how i ll invoke my program as soon as some text comes into that log file.

In other words, how can i keep a check all the time on that file so that whenever some specific text comes into that file, i get alert regarding that text.  any function call? or something else? Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the way i think i would go about it is this:

first of all i will create a bash script and a text file, the bash script will first store the number of lines of that log file in the text file, then add a cron of that script.

the script will count the lines of that file and compare it to the number of lines stored in the text file

you can do that using the command

```
wc -l filename
```

if the number of lines is bigger then the log has been updated, i will calculate the current number of lines minus the number stored in the text field, and by that i will know how many lines have been added since last check, then use this command to fetch those lines

```
tail -n $number_of_lines filename
```

and i will loop through the output and do the desired action if one of the lines matches your criteria and then update the text file which holds the number of lines, i would have written you the bash script but i guess you got the idea

EDIT: you can execute this script (just write your code which searches for the matches etc)

```
#!/bin/bash

NUMBER=`/bin/cat ./numberoflines`
LINES=`/usr/bin/wc -l < /var/log/messages`

DIFFERENCE=$(($LINES-$NUMBER))

if [ $DIFFERENCE != 0 ]; then
tail -n $DIFFERENCE /var/log/messages |while read line
do
if $( echo $line | grep --quiet 'New USB device found' )
then
        # Email text/message
        EMAIL='youremail@gmail.com'
        SUBJECT="New USB device found"
        EMAILMESSAGE="/tmp/emailmessage.txt"
        echo "New USB device found etc ..." > $EMAILMESSAGE
        /bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $EMAILMESSAGE
fi
done
echo "$LINES" > ./numberoflines
fi
```

EVEN if you cannot add anything to crons then you still can execute this script anyway, see what you want to match and check and execute the code you need there

Comment: @ Al-Kateb: This is a good idea but sorry if i didn't mention that I can't add anything in cronjob. I have to write complete function that will be running like any other OS program. can't add this job in crontab.

Comment: you still can execute that script from the command line though, check the updated answer it has a small bash script that helps you do that

Comment: This might get dangerous in a production environment which very big log files (some 10G): during each call of the proposed script the file is completely read - which might be a performance issue.

Comment: @ Al-Kateb: where is the string that i'll mention to search? I am trying to search "New USB device found" in /var/log/messsages and trying to generate an email as soon as a USB is connected. I dont want to use udev or cronjob. just want to do it through script. Here is script that I have adjusted by reading ur provided script:

Comment: #!/bin/bash

NUMBER=`/bin/cat ./numberoflines`
LINES=`/usr/bin/wc -l < /var/log/messages'

DIFFERENCE=$(($LINES-$NUMBER))

if [ $DIFFERENCE != 0 ]; then
 echo "hi"
 tail -n $DIFFERENCE /var/log/messages |while read line
     do
     
     CURDATE=`date +"%m%d%y"`;
     mail -s "USB Connected: CURDATE" alpha@xyz.com  
     
     done
 echo "$LINES" > ./numberoflines
fi

Comment: @user115079 check the updated script it now serves exactly what you need, it will check the new lines in the /var/log/messages when it finds any line that matches the given string it will send an email to youremail@gmail.com, place this script anywhere and create a file next to it named numberoflines and put 0 inside it, as starting number, Andreas Florath I'm thinking tail only gets the end of the file, which will be a small amount of lines so it does not read the whole file which won't make it very slow don't you think

Comment: @AL-Kateb: Thanks alot for your efforts. You are a master. well, I just found a small bug in that program which i jst want to discuss with u.  This program is perfect but numberoffiles doesn't work. dont know why but i've to put full path for it. when i put ./numberoffiles it doesn't work but when i put /u/usb/numberoffiles then it works perfect. may b u can tell better that why its so? Thanks for ur efforts.

Comment: @AL-Kateb: i wud say rather this script sometimes executes and sometimes not..... dont know why...:(

Comment: @user115079 sorry if the script has any errors, i wrote it on the go, but it would help if you tell me when does it work and it does not, anyway I'll run some test and get back to you

Comment: I just finished testing the script and it works just fine, now if when it does not work it does not throw any errors then the problem is probably something different make sure the string ure searching for is always the same, and if it is then I'm suspecting the problem is with sending emails maybe, maybe the queue was full emails got delayed or maybe rejected for any reason, anyway to make sure it is working or not place this after the email sending command echo - "found it" - $line - by this you will know when it is supposed to send an email and when it is not

Comment: yes email can be issue as i get message "email found in /var/spool/mail" when i execute it. but even when i try to make directory (instead of sending email) then too it just executes and then i can't see anything in system process. (ps -ef | grep script). I checked it on my vm and then on my vps. same thing. i can provide you my vps if u can check on it. my email id kashif.live@live.com. Kindly help. I'll be highly thankful to you.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this can get you started. Try this test.sh script out:

```
#/bin/sh

while read line
do
 echo `date` " $line"
done
```

Now try invoking it like this (qwe is a simple text file with some lines):

```
./test.sh < qwe
```

It will read lines form qwe and print them until EOF.

Now invoke it like this:

```
tail -f qwe | ./test.sh
```

Now it will read the lines but it won't stop at EOF but wait for the next line.

If you do this in a separate terminal:

```
`echo "hi" >> qwe`
```

You see..

Answer (score 0):

```
watch -n 0.1 cat /proc/uptime
```

where n is the interval time in seconds.

Do 
    `man watch`
 for more info.